# How can I set my system's default encoding to UTF-16?

Tags: linux, unicode, character-encoding

My daily activity involves usage of English, French, Spanish, and when I save personal copies of web pages or other documents, the full character range of those languages finds its way into filenames as well as file contents.

When I do partition scanning (using find) for filenames for various purposes (spurious character cleanup, stat reports, archiving review), I get reports of

```
Invalid multibyte data detected. There may be a mismatch between your data and your locale.
```

Here is a few of the lines actually reporting that in context:

```
Fri 18 Nov 2022 06:51:33 PM EST  Creating sorted list ... '/DB001_F4/0-DB001_F4-20221118185030.files' ...
 14          Extracting type jpg ...
 15 awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=/DB001_F4/0-DB001_F4-20221118185030.details/0-DB001_F4-20221118185030.            files_jpg FNR=303) warning: Invalid multibyte data detected. There may be a mismatch between your data        and your locale.
 16          Extracting type htm ...
 17 awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=/DB001_F4/0-DB001_F4-20221118185030.details/0-DB001_F4-20221118185030.            files_htm FNR=325) warning: Invalid multibyte data detected. There may be a mismatch between your data        and your locale.
 18          Extracting type txt ...
 19 awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=/DB001_F4/0-DB001_F4-20221118185030.details/0-DB001_F4-20221118185030.            files_txt FNR=322) warning: Invalid multibyte data detected. There may be a mismatch between your data        and your locale.
 20          Extracting type c ...
 21 awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=/DB001_F4/0-DB001_F4-20221118185030.details/0-DB001_F4-20221118185030.files_c     FNR=1006) warning: Invalid multibyte data detected. There may be a mismatch between your data and your        locale.
 22          Extracting type url ...                                                                          
 23 awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=/DB001_F4/0-DB001_F4-20221118185030.details/0-DB001_F4-20221118185030.            files_url FNR=288) warning: Invalid multibyte data detected. There may be a mismatch between your data        and your locale.
```

When I dig further, using Vim to examine the report lists, I see instances similar to this:

[image]

which is showing how it is representing a character in the **extended ASCII character set**.  Instead of "**Â<82>**", it should be showing "**é**".  That character is ubiquitous in the French language.

When I use the following command to show the offending characters by specified range,

```
grep --color='auto' -P "[\x80-\xFF]" *files_htm
```

instead of that same garbage from 'find', I get a report that correctly displays the characters, namely

[image]

Since the message is complaining about a mismatch for my locale (*which is UTF-8, see at bottom*), for proper handling of those characters in all contexts on my Desktop computer, I am considering switching my **Ubuntu MATE 20.04 Desktop** environment from UTF-8 to UTF-16.

a) How can I do that **Post**-Install for my current distro ?

b) How can I do that **Post**-Install for my future distro (22.04) ?

c) If possible, how can I do that **Pre**-Install (*or during the installation*) so that the distro is installed with UTF-16 **from the outset**?

The report for my locale command is as follows:

```
root@OasisMega1:/DB001_F4/0-DB001_F4-20221118185030.details# locale
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_CA:en
LC_CTYPE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
root@OasisMega1:/DB001_F4/0-DB001_F4-20221118185030.details#
```

Comment: How is UTF-16 supposed to help? It can't encode anything that UTF-8 couldn't already

Comment: This is a horrible idea. Typically it is applications that mainly use UTF-8 or UTF-16 for user interaction. The OS itself doesn’t really care. So if you are just doing this to do it… Don’t! You will break something.

Comment: IF the OS doesn't care, why does 'find' give me "junk" and grep reports correctly displayed characters ?????????  Isn't "find" considered an integral part of the OS ?  Shouldn't it, therefore display correctly, instead of giving me "junk" ?

Comment: @DavidPostill, I tried setting UTF-16 as the tag for the question, but that was disallowed.  Since UTF-8 is not perceived as my solution to the problem, I chose Unicode as the only other allowed tag.  Reason is: "for proper handling of those characters in all contexts on my Desktop computer, " as stated in original question.

Comment: @Mokubai, I provided that in my question.  Message reported by 'AWK' processing 'find' filelist report states "Invalid multibyte data detected. There may be a mismatch between your data and your locale".

Comment: @gronostaj, thank you for that. That is good info.  But if the "mismatch" error is not being addressed by UTF-8, how else could I react but to conclude that UTF-16 must be the answer?

Comment: There was a question like this 2 or 3 days ago. No idea if it's from you and where it was now (probably deleted). But I'll put it again simply: it's **impossible to use UTF-16 or UTF-32 on Linux**, because pretty much all syscalls use `char*` which doesn't contain the length and must be null-terminated, therefore the null bytes in UTF-16 and UTF-32 will always make it fail to work. On Windows there are separate APIs for `char*` and `wchar_t*` and by calling the correct API you can use UTF-16. That kind of API simply doesn't exist on \*nix

Comment: @phuclv, thank you.  That was my other question.  Yest it is deleted.  Your previous response did not mention that it was "impossible" to use UTF-16.  I see the reason you gave, but that is explanation seems, to my uninformed mind, baffling!  You are suggesting that Linux, an operating system that is used by the majority of supercomputers, can't correctly handle a more space-consuming character set!  That seems hard to accept without offering a link to an acknowledged industry resource that spells out such a limitation non-ambiguously.  BTW, I have decided to back away from UTF-16.

Comment: @EricMarceau it's not related to Linux. It's the Unix API designed in the '70s when `wchar_t` or Unicode didn't even exist. Even later when POSIX was released then Unicode is still a foreign thing. All file APIs in Unix receive `char*` without a specified length. Linux, being Unix-like, also faces the same issue. Programs can't receive input arguments with embedded NULLs, and files can't be opened with a path with embedded NULLs. The `main()` function won't even run properly because the `_start` function to call it doesn't work

Comment: Thank you again, @phuclv.  I am out of my depth for that discusssion.  I will simply have to face reality and deal with it that way.  Leaving that behind ... am I forced to scan for all those "junk" characters and either renaming files or massaging file contents?  If so, how can I do that safely?

Comment: Unicode support in OSes only appeared in 1993 with Windows NT. Windows was always an early adopter back then, and lots of bad designs in old standards stuck. Windows NT was completely new so MS introduced the new `wchar_t` APIs in parallel, seeing Unicode being the future. At that time UTF-16 didn't exist so Windows used UCS-2. Much later when Unicode was decided not to be a 16-bit charset but a 21-bit one, UTF-16 & UTF-8 came, and Unix began to use UTF-8 exclusively due to its advantages, one of that being no change in the API is required. Since then no one uses UTF-16 anymore

Comment: Thank you, again, for that background and context.  Is that limited to North-American installations, or does that apply globally?

Comment: It's the Windows NT kernel that exclusively uses UTF-16, everything not UTF-16 using the old API is converted internally to UTF-16. \*nix kernels don't care about that, they just store the byte sequence as a NULL-terminated string. Encoding is handled by drivers & apps. You simply need to use UTF-8 everywhere and use tools that explicitly support UTF-8. Not all GNU tools do that, even [awk just got proposed UTF-8 support half a year ago](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=32534173). Perl or python would be a much better tool for UTF-8 handling

Comment: I am stunned that all the major Distro players (Debian, Ubuntu, RedHat, etc.) haven't banded together to encourage/support/finance developers to upgrade their tools (core OS utilities, like find, awk, etc.) to properly handle UTF-8 by now already!  I was under the impression that, given the locale reporting UTF-8 accross the board, all those utilities were correctly conforming.  Your bringing that to my attention was, simply put, like being blind-sided by a Mack Truck!  This has literally changed my world view on my assumptions about Linux!  I have lots of homework to do.

Comment: Yeah I had the same trouble with UTF-8 support in various tools. [GNU `tr` also doesn't support UTF-8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389615/44425). Since then I tend to use PowerShell, python and perl more for complex text-related tasks. I always have PowerShell installed on my Ubuntu, and I use it exclusively on Windows

Comment: I just scanned through the Common, Core and Desktop portions of the Linux Standard Base, https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/lsb.shtml, and found no reference to UTF-8.  Would anyone else expect that to be covered there?  PS, I scanned the Unicode HOWTO, but the version I was able to locate (2000) is too old to be of any relevance to my current issue.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-16 isn't ASCII compatible. Maybe you're not supposed to.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/36592733/728